# 深層学習モデルのandroidアプリへの活用

Tags: python, java, 深層学習

android studioを利用してアプリを作成する際にpythonで作成した深層学習の学習済みモデルをアプリに組み込む方法はありますか？
具体的には画像認識モデルをandroid上で動かしたいのですが
深層学習はkerasで作成しました